# creating list of an elemente multipled n times

Tags: list, prolog

So my problem is this, i have a predicate which is repete_el(El,N,L) in which El is an element, N is the number of times is repeated and L is the list contaning that element repeated N times.

My problem is that istead of repeating the element its giving false and i dont understand why.

Example:

My output:

```
?- repete_el(a,3,L).
false
```

Correct output:

```
?- repete_el(a,3,L).
L = [a,a,a].
```

Program:

```
repete_el(El,0,[]) :- !.

repete_el(El,N,L) :- repete_el(El,N,L,[],N).

repete_el(El,N,L,L2) :- length(L2,C),
                        C =< N,
                        append(L2,[N],NL),
                        repete_el(El,N,L,NL).
```

By the way, i can only do this iteratively.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard `findall/3` predicate and the de facto standard `between/3` predicate. For example:

```
| ?- findall(a, between(1,5,_), List).
List = [a, a, a, a, a]
yes
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this will not work is because at the moment you call `repete_el/4`, `L2` is a free variable, so `length(L2, C)` will start building all sorts of lists with lengths. Then you make a recursive call on a list `NL` with one element extra, and you require that list to have again length `C` (which should again be smaller than `N`). But eventually `C` will be larger than `N`, and thus the predicate will fail.

You can write such predicate as:

```
repete_el(_, 0, []).  %% (1)
repete_el(X, N, [X|T]) :-        %% (2)
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    repete_el(X, N1, T).
```

Here we thus say:

> (1) A list where we repeat an element `0` times is an empty list; and
>    (2) a list where we repeat `X`, `N` times, with `N` greater than `0` is a list that starts with `X` and ends with a list where we repeat `X`, `N-1` times.